# Why Am I Receiving a WhiteLabel Error from hello world SpringBoot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, tomcat

Hi im learning Spring and I don't understand why I am receiving a white label error

MAINCLASS:

```
package com.hello.springhelloworld;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringHelloWorldApplication {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(SpringHelloWorldApplication.class, args);
}

}
```

HELLOWORLDCLASS:

```
package web;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;

@Controller
public class HelloWorldController {

@RequestMapping("/hello")
public String sayHello(@RequestParam(value = "name") String name){
    return  "Hello" + name + "!";
}
}
```

PROJECTSTRUCTURE:
[image]

ERROR:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring boot's component scan is not scanning your controller class.

Your controller class should be on the same package as your SpringHelloWorldApplication class (or in a child package).

so your controller package declaration should be:

```
package com.hello.springhelloworld.web;
```

or

```
package com.hello.springhelloworld;
```

Spring boot's default component scan scans for components on the same package or on a child package of the main app class package.

Answer (score 1):

Issue is component scanning not aware about your web package.

Another way is you can get help of `@ComponentScan("web")` at your Main class.

Below part is addition (Read through your code, and thought to write this).

After you called `/hello?name=World`, if expect it will print "Hello World!". No it won't show up, unless you have a view call this name "Hello World!". Instead of `@Controller` try with `@RestController`. Your message will be print.

Thanks !